# How to update data in mysql from C# texbox

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I'm trying to update data in mysql database on this way:

```
private void executeQuery(string insertQuery)
            {
                MySqlCommand dataCommand = new MySqlCommand();
                using (MySqlConnection dataConnection = new MySqlConnection())
                try
                    {
                        dataConnection.ConnectionString = @"server=localhost;user id=root; password=root; database=pop-sf40-database";
                        dataConnection.Open();
                        dataCommand = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, dataConnection);
                        if (dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Done.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error.");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        dataConnection.Close();
                    }
            }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection dataConnection = new MySqlConnection())
                try
                {
                    dataConnection.ConnectionString = @"server=localhost;user id=root; password=root; database=pop-sf40-database";
                    dataConnection.Open();
                    string updateQuery = "UPDATE `pop-sf40-database`.`salons` SET `id` = '"+ txtSalonId.Text + "', `name` = '" + txtSalonName.Text + "', `adress` = '" + txtSalonAdress.Text + "', `telephone` = '" + txtSalonTelephone.Text + "', `email` = '" + txtSalonEmail.Text + "', `web_site` = '" + txtSalonSite.Text + "', `tin` = '" + txtSalonTin.Text + "', `uid` = '" + txtSalonUid.Text + "', `bank_account` = '" + txtSalonBankAccount.Text + "', `deleted` = '" + 0 + "'";
                    executeQuery(updateQuery);
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    dataConnection.Close();
                }
            txtSalonId.Clear();
            txtSalonName.Clear();
            txtSalonAdress.Clear();
            txtSalonTelephone.Clear();
            txtSalonEmail.Clear();
            txtSalonBankAccount.Clear();
            txtSalonSite.Clear();
            txtSalonTin.Clear();
            txtSalonUid.Clear();
            txtSalonBankAccount.Clear();
        }
```

But, in database Id must be unique, ofcourse. Problem is this: [image]

For example, if I show all salon data in textboxes and change only adress it will still throw ecxception for ID, primary key.

Comment: Might I suggest a read of the following?
 https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to update the `id` in your update SQL, and the `where` clause is missing, so actually you are updating all the records in the `salons` table to the same `id`(2 in your case), that's why the error shown

You should use the `id` in the `where` clause of the update SQL, like:

```
string updateQuery = "UPDATE `pop-sf40-database`.`salons` SET `name` = '" + txtSalonName.Text + "', `adress` = '" + txtSalonAdress.Text + "', `telephone` = '" + txtSalonTelephone.Text + "', `email` = '" + txtSalonEmail.Text + "', `web_site` = '" + txtSalonSite.Text + "', `tin` = '" + txtSalonTin.Text + "', `uid` = '" + txtSalonUid.Text + "', `bank_account` = '" + txtSalonBankAccount.Text + "', `deleted` = '" + 0 + "' WHERE `id` = '"+ txtSalonId.Text + "'" ;
```

Comment: An answer that doesn't address the obvious SQL injection vulnerability does more harm than good, in my opinion.